# Spring 5 add static file directory webapp

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring 5 (not Spring Boot) web application.  I have one controller that outputs html.   I output a string which is HTML and it works, however the relative paths the JS content do not work.  I will layout my structure as follows:

```
src
    main
       java
       resources
       webapp
          css
          js
          img
          WEB-INF
          index.html
    test
       java
       resources
```

When I output my html text, all the relative locations cannot be found:
if I call:
http://localhost:8080/myapp/controller?{some parameters}
I would expect
http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/myjsfile.js
would be there.   When I build and deploy the WAR, the exploded WAR file has all the right code.   So I would expect the file to be there and found.   However, I expect from what I've been reading that static files can be served out differently.   So, I have two questions:

1) What is the standard way of serving static files from a Spring 5 web application?   Do I change the structure this way:

```
  src
    main
       java
       resources
            static
                css
                js
                img
       webapp
          WEB-INF
          index.html
    test
       java
       resources
```

And then I am presuming I have to do the webconfig as such:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("static/js", "static/css", "static/img")
       .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

2) OR, can I use the existing structure and then change the WebConfig to add those static locations as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/js", "css", "img")
       .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

But if putting these files under webapp doesn't work, I can understand moving them to /resources if that is the standard way of doing thing.

So, if I could get any help with this, that will be fine.   I am fine with either way as long as it works.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the resources/static folder to provide your view files. And add the following configuration to your WebMvcConfigurer:

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

It will map all static files requested in the "/" URL to redirect to resources/static folder.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the way to go, place your folder under resources directory (name it as you wish):

```
src/main/java/resources
    myStaticResourcesFolder
        css
        js
        img
```

Then just do this:

> ```
> @Override
> public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
>     registry.addResourceHandler("/**") // map to whatever url you need
>         .addResourceLocations("myStaticResourcesFolder/"); // 
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  I had just tried it based on the other comment.